# Delimited text layer doesn't align with shapefile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a shapefile of 25 major drainage basins of Canada and a .csv file of 77 point data I would like to plot within these drainage basins. I am using QGIS 3.10.9

I reprojected the drainage basins from WGS83 to NAD83/Statistics Canada Lambert EPSG:3347 because I need the measuring unit to be in meters so I can create buffers around point data. The point data are saved as a .csv and I am trying to add them as a delimited text layer (and afterwards will export to shapefile).

When I specify the same CRS (EPSG:3347) and then click ADD, the points show up in a completely different area (and seem way too close together).

I have tried to save as a shapefile, reproject, define projection. None of these seem to work. The points remain off to the left.

Here are some screenshots so you can see - anyone know where I might have gone wrong?

Here is the point data: https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/environmental-indicators/water-quality-canadian-rivers.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your CSV data has coordinated data is some CRS.  You need to assign that CRS when adding the CSV not just use one that you would like it to be in.

Answer (score 1):

The values in the LATITUDE and LONGITUDE columns are already in WGS84, so I think you're going too far in assigning EPSG:3347 to the CSV data.

[image]

[image]

Once you have imported it in WGS 84, you can export it > project to 3347 properly.

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you :)

Comment: @nracine great - and could you re-project the data properly too?

Comment: Yeah it all reprojected fine once I brought it in as WGS 84 and then reprojected it.